# Sorting a listbox bound to an ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, sorting, binding, observablecollection, itemssource

How would one go about sorting my listbox contents? It seems to me that it would make more sense to keep this only on the UI layer since sorting won't affect my business logic, so it probably goes in the xaml or code-behind. I can't figure out what to do exactly though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to use a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) for that.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SomeCollection);
    view.SortDescriptions.Add
    (
        new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Descending)
    );
}
```

To do sorting in XAML you can use the [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) class; Example from MSDN:

```
<src:Places x:Key="places"/>

<CollectionViewSource Source="{StaticResource places}" x:Key="cvs">
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CityName"/>
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
  <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="State"/>
  </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
         DisplayMemberPath="CityName" Name="lb">
```

Comment: any way to do that in xaml instead?

Comment: Yes, i added some more info to my answer.